# Refactoring a slow performing query with a subquery in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, query-optimization

I have a query that is taking too long to execute (600 ms). It is mostly due to having the Distinct keyword, without it it executes in ~20 ms. I've tried to take out the Distinct and use a Group By on visit.participation_id but I didn't see any performance improvements. Here is the original query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."event_id" = $1 AND "participations"."is_preview" = $2 AND ("participations"."id" NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT "visits"."participation_id" FROM "visits" INNER JOIN "ahoy_events" ON "ahoy_events"."visit_id" = "visits"."id" WHERE "visits"."event_id" = $3 AND "visits"."participation_id" IN (SELECT "participations"."id" FROM "participations" WHERE "participations"."event_id" = $4 AND "participations"."is_preview" = $5)))
```

I already have an indexes on Visit participant_id and event_id.

How can this be refactored to not use the Distinct operation or what else can be done? Would a materialized view make sense to use here?

Comment: Don't use **count(*)** because it has to go throught all rows, use **count(event_id)** if event_id is in an index, so it will go faster.

Comment: Removing the `DISTINCT` part from your query should not change the result of your query? You use it only in a `NOT IN` clause and the fact that one Id is there 1 or more times should not make any difference to the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "participations" p2
WHERE p2."event_id" = $1 
   AND p2."is_preview" = $2 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM "visits" 
                   JOIN "ahoy_events" ON "ahoy_events"."visit_id" = "visits"."id" 
                   JOIN  "participations" ON "visits"."participation_id" = "participations"."id"
                   WHERE "visits"."event_id" = $3 
                     AND "participations"."event_id" = $4  
                     AND "participations"."is_preview" = $5
                     AND p2."participation_id" = "participations"."id"))
```